# SSH.NET SFTP client giving "Path does not exists" when connected to Cerberus SFTP server

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET. I am able to connect and I can also see the working directory being returned as "/". But when I try to list files on the same  directory that is being returned, I get the error. same is happening if I call change directory on "/"

> Path does not exists

```
public void DoWork(string host, int port, string user, string password, string passPhrase, string privateKeyFilePath)
    {
        var keyFiles = new[] { new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyFilePath, passPhrase) };

        var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
        methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(user, password));
        methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(user, keyFiles));
        var con = new ConnectionInfo(host, port, user, methods.ToArray());
        var client = new SshClient(con);
        try
        {
            client.Connect();
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
                //    SshCommand getSSHWorkingDirectory = client.RunCommand("pwd");
                //  var workingDirectory = getSSHWorkingDirectory.Result.Trim();
                //   Console.WriteLine("SSH working directory = " + workingDirectory);
                using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(con))
                {
                    sftpClient.Connect();

                    if (sftpClient.IsConnected)
                    {
                        sftpClient.ChangeDirectory(sftpClient.WorkingDirectory);
                        var files = sftpClient.ListDirectory(sftpClient.WorkingDirectory).Select(s => s.FullName);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Disconnect();
        }

    }
```

Using the same key file and credentials and port I can connect using FileZilla and I can see directory. But same kind of setup in code is not working.  I have also tried passing in "." as directory.

[image]

as you can see i am connected. it even shows my working directory as "/" but commands like `ChangeDirectory` or `ListDirectory` not recognizing the path "/".

exception stack-trace is as below.

> at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestOpenDir(String path, Boolean nullOnError)
> at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.ChangeDirectory(String path)
> at Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.ChangeDirectory(String path)
> at eReserveIntegration.Functions.Functions.FetchAndUpload.d__5.MoveNext() in ccccc\FetchAndUpload.cs:line 160
> these are logs from FileZila

[image]

There are logs from WinSCP (I have hidden important information with "xxxx")

```
> . 2020-06-25 02:02:31.911 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.913 WinSCP Version 5.17.6 (Build 10516) (OS 10.0.17134 - Windows 10 Enterprise)
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.913 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.913 Log level: Normal
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.914 Local account: xxxx
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.914 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.914 Process ID: 29188
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.914 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.914 Time zone: Current: GMT-5, Standard: GMT-6 (Central Standard Time), DST: GMT-5 (Central Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/8/2020, DST End: 11/1/2020
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 Login time: Thursday, June 25, 2020 2:02:31 AM
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 Session name: tenent (Site)
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 Host name: sftp.xxxxxx.com (Port: 2222)
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 User name: xxxxxxx (Password: Yes, Key file: Yes, Passphrase: No)
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 Tunnel: No
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 Transfer Protocol: SFTP (SCP)
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 Ping type: Off, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.915 Disable Nagle: No
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 Proxy: None
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 Send buffer: 262144
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 Bypass authentication: No
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: Yes
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 GSSAPI: Forwarding: No; Libs: gssapi32,sspi,custom; Custom: 
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 Ciphers: aes,chacha20,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 KEX: ecdh,dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,rsa,WARN,dh-group1-sha1
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 SSH Bugs: Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 Simple channel: Yes
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.916 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: Auto
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 Shell: default
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 EOL: LF, UTF: Auto
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes; Follow directory symlinks: No
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No; Exit code 1 is error: No
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 SFTP Bugs: Auto,Auto
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 SFTP Server: default
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 Local directory: C:\Users\xxxxxx\xxxxxx, Remote directory: /, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 DST mode: Unix
. 2020-06-25 02:02:31.917 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.073 Looking up host "sftp.xxxxxx.com" for SSH connection
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.090 Connecting to 10.11.xxx.xxx port 2222
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.123 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.17.6
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.123 Remote version: SSH-2.0-CerberusFTPServer_11.0
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.123 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.124 Have a known host key of type rsa2
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.138 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve nistp256 and hash SHA-256
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.215 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.215 ssh-rsa 2048 8d:ed:4b:5a:b1:2a:6a:f0:9f:80:a8:5c:41:48:df:xx tam1gcQz/oPD4oNaFegENZxxxxxxxxxxxx
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 Host key does not match cached key
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 Asking user:
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 **WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!**
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 The server's host key does not match the one WinSCP has in cache. This means that either the server administrator has changed the host key, the server presents different key under certain circumstance, or you have actually connected to another computer pretending to be the server.
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 The new RSA key details are:
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227     Algorithm:    ssh-rsa 2048
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227     SHA-256:  tam1gcQz/oPD4oNaFegENZ3n7tQKxxxxxxxxxxx
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227     MD5:  8d:ed:4b:5a:b1:2a:6a:f0:9f:80:a8:5c:41:48:df:10
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 
. 2020-06-25 02:02:32.227 If you were expecting this change, trust the new key and want to continue connecting to the server, either press Update to update cache, or press Add to add the new key to the cache while keeping the old one(s). If you want to carry on connecting but without updating the cache, press Skip. If you want to abandon the connection completely, press Cancel. Pressing Cancel is the ONLY guaranteed safe choice. ()
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.342 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.342 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 outbound MAC algorithm
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.342 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.342 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 inbound MAC algorithm
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.425 Reading key file "C:\UsersxxxxxxxxxprivateKey.ppk"
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.427 Using username "xxxxxx".
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 Welcome to xxxxxx SFTP Server
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 This system is for the use of authorized users only. Individuals 
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 using this system with authority, without authority, or in excess
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 of their authority, are subject to having all of their activities on 
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 this system scanned, monitored and/or recorded by authorized
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 system personnel. Anyone using this system, expressly consents 
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 to such monitoring and is advised that if such monitoring reveals 
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 possible evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may 
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 provide the evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement 
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.619 officials.
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.620 Server offered these authentication methods: password,publickey
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.620 Offered public key
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.777 Offer of public key accepted
! 2020-06-25 02:02:35.777 Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20200622"
. 2020-06-25 02:02:35.811 Prompt (passphrase, "SSH key passphrase", <no instructions>, "Passphrase for key "rsa-key-20200622": ")
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.181 Sent public key signature
! 2020-06-25 02:02:39.504 Further authentication required
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.553 Further authentication required
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.553 Server offered these authentication methods: password
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.553 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.553 Using stored password.
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.566 Sent password
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.923 Access granted
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.924 Opening main session channel
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.936 Opened main channel
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.949 Started a shell/command
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.983 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.983 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2020-06-25 02:02:39.983 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2020-06-25 02:02:40.000 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2020-06-25 02:02:40.012 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 176, Number: -1
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.012 SFTP version 6 negotiated.
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.012 Server requests EOL sequence "\r\n".
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.012 Server software: Cerberus FTP Server 11.2.1.0 (110201000) by Cerberus, LLC
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013 Server support information (supported2):
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013   Attribute mask: 2BD, Attribute bits: FF, Open flags: 7
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013   Access mask: 3, Open block vector: 0, Block vector: 0, Max read size: 0
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013   Attribute extensions (0)
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013   Extensions (2)
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013     check-file
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013     copy-file
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013 We will use UTF-8 strings as it is mandatory with SFTP version 4 and newer
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013 Changing directory to "/".
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013 Getting real path for '/'
> 2020-06-25 02:02:40.013 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 11, Number: 2832
< 2020-06-25 02:02:40.068 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 72, Number: 2832
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.070 Real path is '/'
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.070 Trying to open directory "/".
> 2020-06-25 02:02:40.070 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 14, Number: 3079
< 2020-06-25 02:02:40.085 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 62, Number: 3079
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.085 Getting current directory name.
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.150 Listing directory "/".
> 2020-06-25 02:02:40.150 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 10, Number: 3339
< 2020-06-25 02:02:40.162 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 47, Number: 3339
> 2020-06-25 02:02:40.162 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 47, Number: 3596
< 2020-06-25 02:02:40.191 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 205, Number: 3596
> 2020-06-25 02:02:40.191 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 47, Number: 3852
< 2020-06-25 02:02:40.217 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 22, Number: 3852
< 2020-06-25 02:02:40.217 Status code: 1
> 2020-06-25 02:02:40.217 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 47, Number: 4100
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.217 Receive;D;0;2020-06-17T23:05:52.000Z;3;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.217 Send;D;0;2020-03-19T15:24:36.000Z;3;"" [0];"" [0];rwxrwxrwx;1
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.217 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T06:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2020-06-25 02:02:40.264 Startup conversation with host finished.
```

Update 2:
I added the library in my project and picked up some diagnostics of the library may be that helps.

```
> Initiating connection to 'sftp.xxxx.com:2222'.
Server version '2.0' on 'CerberusFTPServer_11.0'.
[] Received message 'KeyExchangeInitMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_KEXINIT'.
[] Sending message 'KeyExchangeInitMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_KEXINIT'.
[] Sending message 'KeyExchangeEcdhInitMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT'.
[] Received message 'KeyExchangeEcdhReplyMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY'.
[] Sending message 'NewKeysMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS'.
[] Received message 'NewKeysMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Creating server cipher (Name:aes256-ctr,Key:xxxxxx77D921B3E772516DC1A156D64DDB25F0210639ADC71061A4B2C93202,IV:297EDB63B3518C1A108D73E5AC9C65DF97BFECC2269C84570C39DB74432EA276)
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Sending message 'ServiceRequestMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Received message 'ServiceAcceptMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Sending message 'RequestMessageNone' to server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Received message 'BannerMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Received message 'FailureMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Sending message 'RequestMessagePassword' to server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Received message 'FailureMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Sending message 'RequestMessagePublicKey' to server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST'.
[400981A3B16724C7CAEB4D7C8F6BB609E46552A37A3FE23257B7034F71DD63CB] Received message 'SuccessMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS'.
Initiating connection to 'sftp.xxxx.com:2222'.
Server version '2.0' on 'CerberusFTPServer_11.0'.
[] Received message 'KeyExchangeInitMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_KEXINIT'.
[] Sending message 'KeyExchangeInitMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_KEXINIT'.
[] Sending message 'KeyExchangeEcdhInitMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT'.
[] Received message 'KeyExchangeEcdhReplyMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY'.
[] Sending message 'NewKeysMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS'.
[] Received message 'NewKeysMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Creating server cipher (Name:aes256-ctr,Key:yyyyyyy80B02341081A8E344C28649E069C43C11BB6E2F15069A8AF3DD32A7,IV:653DB595DF140627517691E10D757F532E772483A65B91C8949DDB0D10872B88)
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'ServiceRequestMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'ServiceAcceptMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'RequestMessageNone' to server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'BannerMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'FailureMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'RequestMessagePassword' to server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'FailureMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'RequestMessagePublicKey' to server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'SuccessMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'ChannelOpenMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'ChannelOpenConfirmationMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION : #0'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'ChannelRequestMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST : #201968'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'ChannelSuccessMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_SUCCESS : #0'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'ChannelDataMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #201968'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'ChannelDataMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #0'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'ChannelDataMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #201968'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'ChannelDataMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #0'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'ChannelDataMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #201968'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'ChannelDataMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #0'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Sending message 'ChannelDataMessage' to server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #201968'.
[92823B85114A9C906D4EB1ED23072AD8DBBB0BBA47959E5207E6E0125FE3030E] Received message 'ChannelDataMessage' from server: 'SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA : #0'.
```

or can someone suggest me what sort of checks I can perform within the library?

Comment: I believe that's nothing wrong with your code. The problem will have something to do with an incompatibility of SSH.NET and the Cerberus  server. Unfortunately SSH.NET does not  support logging. Neither it allows you to access lower level feature to do any debugging. The only option would be to download SSH.NET code, build the library yourself and debug it.

Comment: can you think of another library that does SFTP with private key and ssh ?

Comment: My [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library).

Comment: Add some logging to `SftpSession.GetCanonicalPath` and `SftpSession..RequestOpenDir`.

Comment: gave up on this library. Win SCP worked .

Answer (score 2):

So I solved the issue by changing the library to WinSCP

```
public SessionOptions GetFTPClient()
    {
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions();
        sessionOptions.Protocol = Protocol.Sftp;
        sessionOptions.HostName = _settings.FTPHost;
        sessionOptions.PortNumber = 2222;
        sessionOptions.UserName = _settings.FTPUserName;
        sessionOptions.Password = _settings.FTPPassword;
        sessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = Path.GetFullPath("privateKey2.ppk");
        sessionOptions.PrivateKeyPassphrase = _settings.FTPPassPhrase;
        sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint = _settings.FTPSshHostKeyFingerprint;
        return sessionOptions;
    }
```

Password might not be required if you are not doing two-factor authentication.
I was getting an error about *"Further Authentication Required"*, so using password along with passphrase worked for me.

After setting up options like this:

```
using (var session = new Session())
{
    try
    {
        session.ExecutablePath = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "winscp.exe");
        session.Open(GetLOptions());


        TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
        transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;
        var files = session.ListDirectory("/Receive").Files;
        foreach (RemoteFileInfo file in files)
        {
            if (file.IsDirectory == false && file.Name.Length == 10)
            {
                var transferResult = session.GetFiles(file.FullName, Path.GetTempPath() + @"PBAR\" + file.Name, false, transferOptions);

                // Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();
            }

        }


    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        session.Close();
    }
    _traceService.TraceFTPUploadEndEvent();
}
```

This worked for me. I was able to download the files locally.

Comment: Have the same issue: also cannot list files on Cerberus. At the same time, WinSCP works fine. Submitted an issue: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/891